# Is it ethical ✔️ to put a green tick mark in your answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, ethics

I noticed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61095587/299924) a green tick was added which seems to be used to encourage the answer to be accepted.  Is this ethical?

The person also commented that they would like their answer to be upvoted and accepted, which seems to reveal their motives.

[image]

Comment: ✓ it's noise, just edit it out

Comment: I would simply edit it out. It's just noise. Asking op to accept the answer after they already confirmed the the answer solved their problem sounds fine (as long as it's just done once and in a non-aggressive way)

Comment: Alright,  that's cool.

Comment: Looks like a habit the answerer has just picked up and applied to all 4 of their answers today

Comment: I support ✔️ the efforts of the community to deal with  noise  on this site .

Answer (score 41, accepted):

❌ It imparts no semantic meaning. It's simply visual noise, and should be removed via an edit. (The same way meta-commentary along the lines of "I will accept this answer soon" should be edited out.)

It's not an ethical matter, though.

To be clear, there is nothing ethically wrong with accepting your own answer, if you feel that it's the best answer provided to the question. But accepting should be done using the site's actual user interface, not by adding your own emoji.

Comment: "Ethical" was probably too strong a term.  "Overly beggy" perhaps...

Comment: Annoying works, too. :-) The only reason I chose to call out "ethical" is that some people apparently think that it's unethical to accept your own answer. It isn't. The site is designed to allow you to do that.

Comment: @CodyGray the issue is that there is far more significance put on the accepted answer than it needs to be. It's the answer that *most helped the OP* not necessarily *the most correct answer*. There might be a very exhaustive and thorough answer by somebody yet OP posts what worked for them. Self-accepting seems fine in that case - it's *by definition* what most helped the OP if that's what they went with. With that said, sometimes blatantly wrong answers are also chosen which...is not very nice.

Comment: I think it a matter of ethics, actually, because the user is trying to suggest to others that their answer is the solution that OP marked. Even if OP marks another answer, confusion can be introduced to those who aren't very familiar with the site (which is most visitors and a fair amount of registered users).

Comment: I think there is an indication in your answer that this situation was related to "accepting your own answer", however, that is not the case here. The question asker was a different user than the one who introduced the green checkmark.

Comment: I don't understand how "accepting your own answer" is related to the linked question - none of the answers are by OP... If trying usual app/product review rating faking approach (where one puts star rating as first/last line of description of they app/products to confuse readers) is ok on SO then why we are not allowing names with some other diamonds for example?

Comment: @CodyGray Should the user in question be alerted to this post?  It appears they're still doing it(putting the checkmark in their answers).

Comment: @Daedalus Sorry, didn't see your comment. Raise a moderator flag if there's a pattern of behavior you want someone to intervene to stop.