# How to properly use 'ethics' tag to avoid closing the question?

Tags: discussion, ethics

I would like to ask question (re-open one of my questions) about morality, ethic. I know such a question exists and received good feedback, like this one:

[Is it ethical ✔️ to put a green tick mark in your answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396422/is-it-ethical-%ef%b8%8f-to-put-a-green-tick-mark-in-your-answer)

How to properly use 'ethics' tag to avoid closing the question?

Comment: Your question isn't deleted; you could just link to it, rather than including an unformatted copy of it.

Comment: _This is also the first time when question tagged as 'ethics' was closed, because of being opinion-based._ Are you absolutely sure about that? You know about previously closed and deleted questions? And if so, choosing a specific tag could not and should not preclude closing a question if it's appropriate. You can't "properly use a tag" to prevent a question being closed. What you can do is post a question such that close votes are less likely to happen, regardless of the tags you use.

Comment: That's true, but if it would be deleted soon and I would have no access to the Internet or time to check this, then this question would not have any sense. And the problem is that I have no control when this question will be deleted.

Comment: @yivi. No, do not assume that community here is unpredictable. I know some rules exists when the question can be tagged as opinion-based and when not. I just would like to know them so I can avoid this.

Comment: I never said anything of the sort.

Comment: It's up to the community to decide what to close and that's what happened. Other people may weigh in and reopen it.

Comment: @yivi you wrote _close votes are less likely to happen_. That's the nonsense. This is not the matter of probability, but rules.

Comment: _"What you can do is post a question such that close votes are less likely to happen, regardless of the tags you use."_ This means that well written questions are _less likely_ to get closed than poorly written questions are, regardless of the tags you use.

Comment: @RobertLongson no, it is up to the code of conduct, especially in this case - what can be said (ask) here and what now.

Comment: No, it's not nonsene. Close votes cast by community members. If your post more closely aligns to what's appropriate for a site, it's less likely that close votes are going to be cast. If, on the other hand, it does not align to what's considered fitting for a site, it's more likely the post will be closed.

Comment: @yivi. Yes, but it is not up to the community to say what is appriopriate for the site, but it is up to the code of conduct.

Comment: Nobody's been rude or abusive here. Closing is not against the code of conduct.

Comment: @RobertLongson of course, is not. But closing for reasons not in line with code of conduct is. I'm not saying this is the case, I'm asking.

Comment: You are confusing things. The CoC is not particularly relevant in regards to close votes, if at all. Topicality is, which is not governed by the CoC, but by the site's rules and community consensus.

Comment: Please, show us where the CoC says _anything_ about what can, and can't be asked on Meta.

Comment: Take, for example, this question. Since it makes assumptions that does not make a lot of sense (like using certain tags would make closing a question less likely),  I find the question "unclear", and I may vote to close as such. I would be using my votes and my interpretation of the rules. That's exactly what's expected from users.

Comment: Please, post this as answer

Answer (score 7):

> How to properly use 'ethics' tag to avoid closing the question

You can't.

There is no tag that magically makes a question immune to *any* closure reason.
<sub>(Aside from official [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement)posts maybe)</sub>

The community votes on your question. If the majority of users deem the question to be off-topic, for whatever reason, the question will get closed.